Possible to refer to a field in an anonymous struct
Is there a way to refer to what is _field_1 in this anonymous struct/ row type?
select (1,2) a


Trying to do:
select a._field_1 from (select (1,2) a)

Gives an error:


select a[0] from (select (1,2) a)


Thanks, select struct(1,2)[0] as well -- is that documented anywhere?
